# Is there any possibly way that new can change a variable?

Tags: c++, new-operator

After

```
void f()
{
    class C { /* some complicated or unusual declaration */ };
    char *p = malloc(sizeof(C);
    C *pc = new(p) C;
    assert(p == (char *)pc);
}
```

Is there any possible way that the assert fails? I'm asking because I can see this behavior in my code.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it?

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully in your spirit, and voted to reopen. It has probably an answer somewhere already but I find it interesting.

Comment: I wondered the same thing. I assume that the operator returns a pointer only so that it resembles the one without parameter, even though it is redundant for placement new.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't think it's appopriate to attribute someone else's code to OP as you have done. This code might be nothing to do with what they actually have in their code. Would suggest reverting .

Comment: Also, this code doesn't "change a variable"; it was an unfounded assumption of dxiv that unexpected return value of placement-new is what OP was trying to describe

Comment: @M.M No such assumption on my part. The "*could not possibly modify the original pointer*" part of my answer directly addresses OP's question as first worded.

Comment: @dxiv After `new(p) foo`, `p` is not modified even if the result of `new` does not equal `p`. They said specifically "`p` is not the same" .

Comment: @M.M Right. That was the first thing in my answer: "*[the placement new operator] takes the void *ptr argument by value, which means it receives a copy of the pointer value, and* ***could not possibly modify the original pointer***". I edited it since to make the separation even more clear from the other part about the return value.

Comment: @dxiv yes, so I doubt that the code now in the question represents OP's situation, since they were in fact claiming the original pointer was modified

Comment: @M.M I tend to agree with that. Maybe the OP will chime in and clarify, as suggested.

Comment: @M.M The question was poorly worded. I understood it as "p is not the same *as the return value."*

Answer (score 2):

If you've done anything that causes Undefined Behavior prior to calling new, then anything can happen.  Having new apparently change unrelated variables is a common symptom of having corrupted the heap internal data structures.

Comment: Is this really a "common" symptom? N.B. this is placement `new` so `p` is probably not pointing to dynamically allocated memory... and, even if it were, the pointer itself is almost _certainly_ not dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 1):

The [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) operator is declared as `void *operator new(std::size_t count, void *ptr);`.

In particular, it takes the `void *ptr` argument by value, which means it receives a copy of the pointer value, and could *not* possibly modify the original pointer.

Also, the pointer returned by the placement new operator is guaranteed to match the `ptr` value passed as argument, per 17.6.3.4/2 [[new.delete.placement]](https://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete.placement):

> ```
> [[nodiscard]] void* operator new(std::size_t size, void* ptr) noexcept;
>
>     Returns: ptr.
> ```

It is however possible for the pointer returned by the placement new operator to get cast to a different pointer than passed into it after automatic type conversions (not related to the placement new call).

For example:

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };
struct C : public A, B {};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    void *p = malloc(sizeof(C));
    B *q = new(p) C();
    std::cout << (p == q) << ": " << p << " " << q << std::endl;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/PG54fj):

```
0: 0x4cdeb0 0x4cdeb4
```

Comment: But what's coming back from new() is probably still p! That pointer conversions to base classes can change the address is not related to placement new.

Comment: In this example placement new still returns the same pointer, and the different address is for a reason that has nothing to do with placement new, whatsoever.

Comment: TINAA ;-).......

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Re-edited to clarify better ;-)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Re-edited to clarify better.